# .accordion() menu snapping before other div's

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem with my Vertical Menu, made with jQuery UI's .accordion() function. It automatically snaps before my Horizontal Menu (when you click the option "games" it should open this menu). How can i set it so that it stays behind the Horizontal Menu? I already tried adjusting z-index, but if it is set to a negative nuber, it stops working. However it doesn't snap before the Horizontal Menu

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color.plus-names-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
        <body>

        <!--        Header      -->
        <a href="index.html"><div id="header">
            <img id="elderscrollslogo" src="elderscrollslogo.png">
            <img id="elderscrollstext" src="The_Elder_Scrolls.png">
        </div></a>
        <!--        xxx         -->


        <!--        Horizontal Menu         -->
        <div class="H-menu" id="glow">
            <div class="option" id="games">Games</div>
            <div class="option">Media</div>
            <div class="option">Items</div>
            <div class="option">News</div>
            <div class="option">Search</div>
            <div class="open"></div>
            <div class="option" id="settings">Settings
                <img id="gear" src="gear.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--        xxx         -->


        <!--        Vertical Menu           -->
        <div class="V-menu">
            <div class="accordionheader">DLC</div>
            <div class="option">
                <ul id="dlc">
                    <li>Dawnguard</li>
                    <li>Hearthfire</li>
                    <li>Dragonborn</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="accordionheader">Armor</div>
            <div class="option">
                <ul id="dlc">
                    <li>Heavy Armor</li>
                    <li>Light Armor</li>
                    <li>Clothing</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="accordionheader">Weapons</div>
            <div class="option">
                <ul id="weapons">
                    <li>Daggers</li>
                    <li>Maces</li>
                    <li>Swords</li>
                    <li>War Axes</li>
                    <br>
                    <li>Battleaxes</li>
                    <li>Greatswords</li>
                    <li>Warhammers</li>
                    <br>
                    <li>Bows</li>
                    <li>Arrows</li>
                    <li>Crossbows</li>
                    <li>Bolts</li>
                </ul>
            </div>          

            <div class="accordionheader">Items</div>
            <div class="option"></div>

            <div class="accordionheader">Quests</div>
            <div class="option"></div>

            <div class="accordionheader">NPC's</div>
            <div class="option"></div>

            <div class="accordionheader">Races</div>
            <div class="option"></div>

            <div class="accordionheader">Perks</div>
            <div class="option"></div>

            <div class="accordionheader">Skills</div>
            <div class="option"></div>

            <div class="accordionheader">Capital Cities</div>
            <div class="option"></div>

            <div class="accordionheader">Cities</div>
            <div class="option"></div>
        </div>
        <!--        xxx         -->


        <!--        Second Menus            -->
        <div id="containercontainer">

            <!--        Settings Menu           -->
            <div id="containersettings">
                <div class="s-o">Account</div>
                <div class="s-o">Privacy</div>
                <div class="s-o" id="last2">Logout</div>
            </div>
            <!--        xxx         -->

            <!--        Games Menu          -->
            <div id="containergames">

                <a href="LAT.html">
                    <div class="g-o">L.A.T.
                    <img class="imggames" src="LAT.jpg">
                </div>
                </a>

                <a href="arena.html">
                    <div class="g-o">Arena
                    <img class="imggames" src="arena.jpg">
                </div>
                </a>

                <a href="daggerfall.html">
                    <div class="g-o">Daggerfall
                    <img class="imggames" src="daggerfall.jpg">
                </div>
                </a>

                <a href="morrowind.html">
                    <div class="g-o">Morrowind
                    <img class="imggames" src="morrowind.jpg">
                </div>
                </a>

                <a href="oblivion.html">
                    <div class="g-o">Oblivion
                    <img class="imggames" src="oblivion.jpg">
                </div>
                </a>

                <a href="skyrim.html">
                    <div class="g-o">Skyrim
                    <img class="imggames" src="skyrim.jpg">
                </div>
                </a>

                <a href="online.html">
                    <div class="g-o" id="last1">Online
                    <img class="imggames" src="online.jpg">
                </div>
                </a>

            </div>
            <!--        xxx         -->
        </div>
        <!--        xxx         -->
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    background-image: url("carbon_background.jpg");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cgoogleover;
}
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
div div {
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}



#header {
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%-10px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(right bottom, rgb(61, 60, 61) 21%, rgb(110, 110, 110) 68%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right bottom, rgb(61, 60, 61) 21%, rgb(110, 110, 110) 68%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right bottom, rgb(61, 60, 61) 21%, rgb(110, 110, 110) 68%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right bottom, rgb(61, 60, 61) 21%, rgb(110, 110, 110) 68%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right bottom, rgb(61, 60, 61) 21%, rgb(110, 110, 110) 68%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, right bottom, left top, color-stop(0.21, rgb(61, 60, 61)), color-stop(0.68, rgb(110, 110, 110)));
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 100;
}
#elderscrollslogo {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    animation: rotate 5s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: rotate 5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes rotate {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}


#elderscrollstext {
    width: 498px;
    height: 62.33333333px;
}
.H-menu {
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #3B5998;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
.H-menu .option {
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #3B5998;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.H-menu .open {
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #3B5998;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}



.V-menu {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #3B5998;
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 0px;
    top: 120px;
}
.V-menu .option {
    float: top;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #3B5998;
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    border: black 1px solid;
}



#dlc    {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    float: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#armor    {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    float: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#weapons    {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    float: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}



.accordionheader    {
    float: top;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #7894CC;
    height: 25px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    border: black 1px solid;
}


#gear {
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    margin-top: -2px;
}
#containercontainer {
    overflow: auto;
}



.s-o {
    list-style-type: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: #7894CC;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 15%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
.g-o {
    list-style-type: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: #7894CC;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 80px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    border: #A3A3A3 solid 1px;
}
.imggames {
    width: 75px;
    height: 110px;
}
#last1 {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
#last2 {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}


#search {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 60%;
    width: 15%;
    background-color: #7894CC;
}


#Text  {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;

    width: 750px;
    height: auto;
    left: 200px;
    right: auto;
    border-radius: 15px;
    top:  175px;

    opacity: 0.9;

    background-color: #008080;

    text-align: center;
    color: #800000;
}
```

jQuery/Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("img").mousedown(function () {
        return false;
    });

    $(".s-o, .g-o").hide();

    $(".H-menu .option").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#7894CC"});
    });
    $(".H-menu .option").mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#3B5998"});
    });

    $( ".V-menu" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true
    });


    $("#settings").click(function () {
        $(".s-o").show();
        $(".s-o").animate({
            opacity: 1.0
        });        
    });

    $("#containersettings").mouseleave(function () {
        $(".s-o").animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, function () {
            $(".s-o").hide();
        });
    });

    $("#games").click(function () {
        $(".g-o").show();
        $(".g-o").animate({
            opacity: 1.0
        });
    });
    $("#containergames").mouseleave(function () {
        $(".g-o").animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, function () {
            $(".g-o").hide();
        });
    });

});
```

jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Fqc53/

Comment: `z-index` only effects elements that have a position value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try setting the `#containercontainer` style to

```
#containercontainer {
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Which seems to be putting the drop down in front of the accordion?

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fqc53/2/)